# Regular expression to match a certain domain and last part of URL

Tags: regex, url

I'm working on a redesign of a site and as part of it we've changed te URL schema, as we want to redirect all old URL to the new ones I'm struggling to get this to work

The old URL are like this

/shop/category/subcategory1/subcategory2/slug

/shop/category/subcategory3/slug

/shop/category/slug

And the new ones look like this

domain.com/new/slug

I need a regular expression to match url starting with "/shop/category" and get the last part of the url as it is the slug of the product

I can get the last part of the URL with this:

`([^\/]+$)`

And match the start of the URL with

`^shop\/category\/`

But I can't find a way to to both at the same time

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^shop\/category(?:\/.*)?\/([^\/]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dzIEgd/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `shop\/category` - a `shop/category` string
- `(?:\/.*)?` - an optional occurrence of a `/` char and then any zero or more chars other than line brea chars as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hello @wiktor-stribiżew, thanks a lot! Works like charm, one question is there a way to use the same regex to detect this url ending with or without /? I've found some places where URL have it at the end and then the regex is not firing

Comment: @Pol It is easy, add an optional char at the end, `^shop\/category(?:\/.*)?\/([^\/]+)\/?$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor, I've updated your post as I hadn't enoguth rep points at the beggining